# RDP and DNS issues when I start OpenVPN

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, remote-desktop, openvpn

Already searched a lot, also here, I have installed OpenVPN Server on Windows Server 2008 r2, it worked smoothly for a time, now when I start OpenVPN service it drops RDP and other services.

I have a static IP and a domain with that IP pointing to my server, let's call it mydomain.com and 200.X.X.X.

When OpenVPN is down i can access RDP, Webpages and systems without any issue.

When I start OpenVPN the only thing I can do is ping to mydomain.com (and it resposes).

Here is my routes on OpenVPN started/Stopped

OpenVPN Started
[image]

My Config File 
http://pastebin.com/yP6UZwJ4

The question would be

How do i make that all the services continue working with OpenVPN Service Started?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: OpenVPN Stopped
http://i47.photobucket.com/albums/f195/warbandit69/OpenVPN%20Stopped_zpstb2abqbl.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved this issue, I had to add the route 10.8.0.0/24 to the routing tables (on the router) and everything started to run smoothly